# Exim error SMTP call from [X.X.X.X]:50135 dropped: too many syntax or protocol error

Tags: smtp, exim, protocol

My clients server access keeps getting blocked by CSF.
The Exim log produces:

> no host name found for IP address X.X.X.X
>   Exim error SMTP call from [X.X.X.X]:50135 dropped: too many syntax or protocol error.

Am I correct in assuming that this can only be solved by the ISP or connectivity provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of reverse DNS record is something that should be addressed/facilitated by the owner of the ip-address, typically indeed the ISP or connectivity provider.

The is not the cause of the second error:

> too many syntax or protocol error

That is caused a crappy SMTP client that doesn't adhere to the standards (which is typically a good indication of a Spambot).

You can tune that behaviour with the [`smtp_max_synprot_errors`](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-smtp_processing.html) setting.

Comment: Thanks HBruijn. The client's email software sends mail using single quotation marks ie 'someone@somewhere.com' she has been using this for a while why is the server only blocking her now?

Comment: I can't determine that either from the information your provide...